# SQL Server 2005 user permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions

I have created a database and some dbo.tables. Now I want to create a user that are can read and write to these tables, but not modify or drop. However I want this user to be able to create own tables and let him do what he want with these.

Is this possible? Could someone explain how this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

You would assign the user to `db_datareader` & `db_datawriter` roles for the `dbo` schema.

However, to allow the user to create and modify only new tables; you would have to create a different schema and assign, for example `db_owner` permissions to this schema.

You should be aware though, that doing this may create problems as you can have two tables with the same name under different schemas.  So you should ensure that your queries always state the owner of the object.

e.g.

```
dbo.MyTable

CustomSchema.MyTable
```

UPDATE:

Ok, I think these are the steps you need to take:

1. Create a new Database Role e.g `db_ReportingRole` and add the relevant user to this role.
2. Create a new Schema e.g `Reporting` and make `db_ReportingRole` the owner of this schema.
3. Assign the relevant `CREATE`, `DROP`, etc permissions to the `db_ReportingRole`
4. Ensure that the same user added previously is in the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles for the `dbo` schema.

This should then allow you to have a user that can read and write to `dbo` schema but should be able to modify tables etc.  However, because they in the `db_ReportingRole` they should have full access to modify, create, drop etc table in the `Reporting` schema. (Providing that you have assigned the correct permissions to the `db_ReportingRole`

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
How does I let the user use the new schema? Does I just change the default schema to the new schema or do I make the user owner of the new schema?

Comment: When I'm creating the new schema and tries to add the permissions. I can't find the database role db_owner

Comment: Hi Karl,  this may help you when trying to assign permissions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx

Comment: You can either assign CREATE, SELECT permissions etc to the schema or create new database roles for the schema and assign permissions that way.  Then add the user to the new database roles.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it right. I have created a new schema Schema_1. The owner for this schema is dbo. I have also Granted everything for a user User_1 in this schema, but when loging in as User_1 and trying to create a table it says the user doesn't have create table permission.

Comment: When you create the table are using the fully qualified name?

e.g.  Create Table Schema_1.MyNewTable